# How can I Invoke item from a listview

Tags: vb.net, ui-automation

I'm trying invoke a item from a ListView with the code below but it's returning an exception in the Try block `InvalidOperationException`.

However, Inspect shows that the Invoke command is available (including through the Action menu of Inspect I ran Invoke and it worked perfectly)

[image: Inspect]

Here's my code.

```
Private Sub Click()

[CODE BEFORE]

  Dim Level4_3_1_1_1_1_1 As Integer = Win32.FindWindowEx(Level4_3_1_1_1_1, vbNullString, "SysListView32", vbNullString)

        Dim List = AutomationElement.FromHandle(Level4_3_1_1_1_1_1)

        If List Is Nothing Then Return
        Dim ListItemsCondition = New OrCondition(
    New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.DataItem),
    New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.ListItem))

        Dim childItems = List.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, ListItemsCondition)
        If childItems.Count = 0 Then Return
        For Each Itens As AutomationElement In childItems
            Dim subItems = List.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, ListItemsCondition)

            If Itens.Current.Name = "AAA000" Then
                Dim invokePattern As InvokePattern = Nothing
                Dim SelectItem As SelectionItemPattern = CType(Itens.GetCurrentPattern(SelectionItemPattern.Pattern), SelectionItemPattern)
                SelectItem.Select()
                Try
                    Dim ClickItem As InvokePattern = DirectCast(Itens.GetCurrentPattern(invokePattern.Pattern), InvokePattern)
                    ClickItem.Invoke()
                Catch ex As ElementNotEnabledException
                    ' // Object is not enabled
                    Return
                Catch ex As InvalidOperationException
                    '// object doesn't support the InvokePattern control pattern
                    Return
                End Try
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: A `ControlType.ListItem` doesn't necessarily support the `InvokePattern`. A SysListView32 ListItem may not have it. The `SelectionItemPattern` will instead work. Remove this: `Dim invokePattern As InvokePattern = Nothing`: it's clearly wrong and it will also *confuse* the compiler. -- You should use `TryGetCurrentPatter()`. Inspect shows all possible patterns: you probably didn't try to actually use it. Are you may trying to change Directory? Note what happens when you open a new View in the Explorer tree.

Comment: Also, you're probably getting all `ControlType.DataItem` elements here.